# Git + Webpack, rebase troubles

Tags: git, webpack, git-rebase

I am using webpack for react development, today I tried to rebase a "feature" branch into master, Git complains that the webpack bundled file has conflicts. Of course the source code of the bundled.js is impossible to use to resolve such conflicts as the bundled file includes every sort of files that it bundles.

How does one usually go about rebasing when you have two or more branches that create its bundled file independently, but clearly only the final commit/rebase's sources of these bundles matter.

thank you

Comment: add the bundled files to `.gitignore`, usually `dist` folder

Comment: Thanks! Because I am using rails with heroku, I do need it to be in the version control to be uploaded. Any other suggestion?

Comment: Is this a limitation of using rails? Normally you would add a `postinstall` script in your `package.json`.. after pushing to heroku your postinstall script can run your webpack build command.

Comment: No, it's no just rails. As webpack generates bundled.js in master and in dev branch, whenever I try to rebase dev into master, it complains that bundled.js is in conflict and I have to resolve it. Of course, no body really cares conflicts in bundled.js, only the source files that generate it. So my question is, how do people deal with this generally? Thanks!

Comment: `dist` folder is in `.gitignore` so bundles never have conflicts. You write a [postinstall script](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#customizing-the-build-process) that builds your `dist` folder after deploying.

Comment: I see, I'll have to see how this is done with Heroku; I had the feeling that we don't check in bundled file when we have its sources, too; but wasn't sure if Heroku lets you do any post-push scripting.

Comment: The link I provided in my comment is straight from the heroku for node docs.

Comment: Thanks!  Didn't follow the link til now. But my app is a rails app, will that postinstall hook get triggered?

Comment: Sorry I'm not 100% sure how it works with rails, but I bet somebody with heroku support could respond. Ther **must** have post install hooks for everything, just like a regular git commit hook.

Answer (score 0):

Probably too late, but this is what I can think of.

One option is to not include the bundle outputs in git. So to run the app locally or on the server, one will have to add 'webpack' as part of the deployment script.

Second option, if you want to keep bundles in version control, is to resolve conflicts by taking any of ours or theirs and then running webpack again to create bundle for the merged code. This will obviously come as local changes in git status. So this will be committed again thus creating a new commit for only the final bundle files.